# How to append multiple text files and put each file name in a new column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, file, text

I have many `*.txt` files in a folder, each file has the same structure:
same four columns but different number of rows in each file.

```
1.txt
  0.00781238   0.00082577   0.00781238  -0.03314453
  0.01562476   0.00064219   0.01562476  -0.03145172
  0.02343713  -0.00105686   0.02343713  -0.03775329
  0.03124951  -0.00016571   0.03124951  -0.00232971
  0.03906189   0.00240464   0.03906189   0.04244080

2.txt
  0.00781238  -0.00409547   0.00781238  -0.01004241
  0.01562476   0.00239794   0.01562476   0.03342835
  0.02343713  -0.00112586   0.02343713   0.00152711
  0.03124951   0.00374492   0.03124951   0.03581025
  0.03906189   0.00124744   0.03906189  -0.01969909
  0.04687427   0.00192426   0.04687427   0.05292329
  0.05468665   0.00266910   0.05468665   0.02569642
```

and more txt files from 1 to 65.

I want to have the result like this

```
Samplename   value1       value2       value3       value4  
1.txt        0.00781238   0.00082577   0.00781238  -0.03314453
1.txt        0.01562476   0.00064219   0.01562476  -0.03145172
1.txt        0.02343713  -0.00105686   0.02343713  -0.03775329
1.txt        0.03124951  -0.00016571   0.03124951  -0.00232971
...            
2.txt
2.txt
...
65.txt
```

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question. Show us what you have tried so far. Show us some code. Your input files kind of `csv` files with spaces of different length as field separators. Another approach would be to read that files as they are, split each line by blanks and build it up again as a real csv file. Then you can to `pandas.read_csv()` with that new file.

Answer (score 1):

Find the files using os.walk, then concat the individual dataframes created from each file:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

txtfolder = r'/home/bera/Desktop/textfiles/' #Change to your folder path

#Find the textfiles
textfiles = []
for root, folder, files in os.walk(txtfolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            textfiles.append(fullname)
textfiles.sort() #Sort the filesnames

#Read each of them to a dataframe
for filenum, file in enumerate(textfiles, 1):
    if filenum==1:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['value1','value2','value3','value4'], delim_whitespace=True)
        df['Samplename']=os.path.basename(file)
    else:
        tempdf = pd.read_csv(file, names=['value1','value2','value3','value4'], delim_whitespace=True)
        tempdf['Samplename']=os.path.basename(file)
        df = pd.concat([df, tempdf], ignore_index=True)
        
df = df[['Samplename','value1','value2','value3','value4']] #Reorder columns

#    Samplename    value1    value2    value3    value4
# 0       1.txt  0.007812  0.000826  0.007812 -0.033145
# 1       1.txt  0.015625  0.000642  0.015625 -0.031452
# 2       1.txt  0.023437 -0.001057  0.023437 -0.037753
# 3       1.txt  0.031250 -0.000166  0.031250 -0.002330
# 4       1.txt  0.039062  0.002405  0.039062  0.042441
# 5       2.txt  0.007812 -0.004095  0.007812 -0.010042
# 6       2.txt  0.015625  0.002398  0.015625  0.033428
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
df = pd.concat(
    (pd.read_csv(f"{n}.txt", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
       .assign(Samplename=f"{n}.txt")
     for n in range(1, 66)),
    ignore_index=True
).rename(columns={n: f"value{n + 1}" for n in range(4)})
df = df[["Samplename"] + list(df.columns[:-1])]
```

- Reading the `n.txt` files with `pandas.read_csv()` (whitespace as delimiter, no header), adding the current filename in a column named `Samplename`, and concatenating the resulting dataframes into one.
- Renameming the 4 numbered columns.
- Moving the column `Samplename` to the front (cosmetic).

Or a bit more generic, if you don't want to fix the number of files:

```
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.concat(
    (pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
       .assign(Samplename=file.name)
     for file in Path().glob("*.txt") if file.stem.isdigit()),
    ignore_index=True
).rename(columns={n: f"value{n + 1}" for n in range(4)})
df = df[["Samplename"] + list(df.columns[:-1])]
```

Another alternative which builds the dataframe directly:

```
import csv
from fileinput import input as finput

with finput(f"{n}.txt" for n in range(1, 66)) as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        ([file.filename(), *map(float, values)]
         for values in csv.reader(file, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)),
        columns=["Samplename"] + [f"value{n}" for n in range(1, 5)]
    )
```

- [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) from [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) facilitates compact reading from several files in a row.
- [`.filename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.filename) gives access to the current filename.